# how to go from back to front camera on arkit

Tags: ios, swift, camera, arkit

This code is just a simple arkit. In the button I would like the user to click to switch back and forth between seeing arkit on the back camera to the front camera.

```
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
let augmentedRealitySession = ARSession()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    augmentedRealityView.session.run(configuration)

    augmentedRealityView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true
}

@IBAction func place(_ sender: Any) {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARKit world tracking doesn’t support the front camera, so there’s no way to switch to it.

ARKit face tracking supports the front camera, but...

- it doesn’t work at all like world tracking — no plane detection, no world coordinate system, no hit testing, etc — so switching configurations completely changes the behavior of your AR experience.
- it requires TrueDepth camera, so it works only on iPhone X.